# VB.Net Edit object attribute using attribute name(string)

Tags: vb.net, attributes

I have a text file listing attribute names and new values. How can I do this in Visual Basic?

Currently I use a series of if statements - but this is very clumsy

```
If attrName = "checking" then
   Me.checking = newValue
End If
```

Comment: can you explain more? Why don't you use [Select...Case Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/select-case-statement)

Comment: You might consider using a `Dictionary` where the attribute names are the keys.

Comment: With *Attributes*, do you mean Property values? If that's the case, you can use Project Settings or custom a Settings file. Unless this the *text file* must be used as-is (e.g., it comes from an external source). In this case, you can still use Settings, assigning a value to the Setting which has the same name of these *attributes* or through reflection, using the Property name to identify the corresponding attribute. A better description of the context would help a lot.

Comment: I am familiar with python and __dict__ so that led me to look at this approach. I will check how to do this using Settings as the text file does come from an external source. I will also look at creating a dictionary. The application is taking transactions from operators as they start and end jobs throughout their shift, this needs to be put into a database and also viewed by supervisors in a VB application using a datagrid or similar. (Trying to provide greater functionality than the spreadsheet methods currently used)